# How to Resubmit Android App after app removed from playstore for policy violation?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

I had used stripe sdk for my android application. I submitted the application and it was initially rejected for uploading **users phone number and installed application information via stripe sdk**. I then, resubmitted the app, removing stripe packages used in my app. But again I am facing the same issue. Is there any other procedure to resubmit the app?

[image]

Comment: what is the stripe sdk version that you are using?

Comment: I had used old sdk version. I removed sdk verison and resubmitted the app but same reply got from google review team.